# IIS 6 and PHP on Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, php

I am trying to get IIS 6 to serve up PHP pages.

I have followed: http://www.iisadmin.co.uk/?p=4&page=3

But now with PHP 3.2 I dont see PHPisapi.dll anyplace so it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I downloaded the .zip for 5.3 Windows non-thread safe and manually put in at c:\PHP.

I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this tutorial](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/) (using FastCGI as opposed to ISAPI) help?

Comment: @ircmaxwell - I have always read that FastCGI does not function as well as ISAPI

Comment: Not always true: http://forums.iis.net/t/1146597.aspx  Not to mention that FastCGI is LOADS more stable (since there are a lot more servers running FastCGI than there are ISAPI for PHP)...  And not to mention that the MS recommended SAPI for IIS7 is FastCGI...  That should tell you something ;-)

Comment: OK, I tried the automated install which says it was successful with no luck. I put a index.php in my default site and added index.php as the only document to be served. I supposed I should try a manual install now

Answer (score 0):

Call me lazy, but I really think Microsoft's [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) makes IIS/PHP (along with MySQL) installation and configuration *so* much easier than the old & manual way. Check a few boxes and let it do the rest.

Comment: I did this, it wasn't working, so I went through manually and everything is set right, but I try and hit my default site and I get a page not found (404). It does exist. If I put an index.html it works, if I put an HTML and re-direct using JavaScript to index.php I still get a 404. I believe my permissions are correct.

Comment: If it failed when Web Platform Installer tried there may be a bit more going on than you've shared? In IIS Admin, is PHP listed under Web Service Extensions? (and is it enabled)

Comment: yes under Web Service Extensions I have: FastCGI Handler and it is Allowed. What other questions can I answer to get more help?

Comment: I am, for the moment, quite stumped as to what to suggest next. Make sure no FPSE is involved on the server, check to ensure you have MIME type for PHP configured?